# Making Starling FrameWork to work with Classes that uses native DisplayObject

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, displayobject, gsap, starling-framework

I'm trying to use Greensock LoaderMax on a Starling Framework project, but since Starling have a lots of its own class, how I can make it work with other classes that is using the native class?

Exp:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import starling.core.Starling

    [SWF(width="1280",height="800",frameRate="60",backgroundColor="#002143")]

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var mStarling:Starling

        public function Main():void
        {
            mStarling = new Starling(Game, stage)
            mStarling.antiAliasing = 1
            mStarling.start()
        }
    }
}

package
{
    import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
    import com.greensock.loading.display.ContentDisplay;
    import com.greensock.loading.SWFLoader;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;

    public class Game extends Sprite
    {       
        private var queue:SWFLoader
        private var mm:ContentDisplay

        public function Game():void
        {
            if (stage)
                init()
            else
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            queue = new SWFLoader("MainMenu.swf", {onComplete: completeHandler})
            queue.load()
        }

        private function completeHandler(e:LoaderEvent):void
        {
            mm = queue.content
            addChild(mm)
        }   
    }
}
```

will return the error:

```
 Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type com.greensock.loading.display:ContentDisplay to an unrelated type starling.display:DisplayObject.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `MainMenu.swf` main class needs to `extend starling.display.Sprite`

since they are a different structure and etc... flash can not transform native sprite to starling sprite.

then after load complete:

`mm = queue.content as Sprite; // ( starlig )`

if you still want to use the normal DisplayObjects and Starling displayObjects, You need to place them in a different mc / sprites which extends different displayObjects.

stage

|...|

starling.display.Sprite -> Here you adding normal Starling Based Sprites / MovieClips

|...|

flash.display.Sprite -> here you adding native Sprites / MovieClips